# How do I create a systemd timer running an event twice a month?

Tags: systemd, schedule

I am simply not able to figure out how to create a systemd timer that is run twice a month. Every two weeks would work also. Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: What about https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191270?

Comment: What would twice a month be if a cron job rebooted system every Sunday at 3 am? eg wouldn't you want a job that runs on the 15th and last day of month? What job are you running twice a month or bi-weekly and why does it have to run in systemd?

Answer (score 2):

Run the timer weekly.

Trivia: The `date` command keeps track of weeks. It even numbers the weeks (1-53). You can use this example of shell-fu to determine if today is in an even-numbered week or an odd-numbered week.

`[ $(( $(date +%V) % 2)) -eq 0 ] && echo "Even Week" || echo "Odd Week"`

Adapt this kind of logic to determine if the rest of your script should run.

(Obviously, with 53 weeks, your end-of-year needs a bit more logic).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's not possible to do a bi-weekly or "every 2nd week" systemd timer. So I've been looking all over for something that currently can't be done. A feature request here: https://is.gd/d2tBIs

Comment: Crude workaround : In your script, set a flag at the end of its run. Then at the start of its run, if the flag is set, unset the flag and quit. If it is not set, run the script. On a weekly schedule, the script will run every other week.